# Mockito vs H2-In Memory to test a project that uses Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit

In a project that I am working on I have used Hibernate to interact with the database. I am trying to test the methods in the Hibernate class. I came across two things.

```
1. Mockito
2. H2-In Memory for testing
```

Here is my class

**UserDAOImpl.java**

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);
    private static Session session;

private static void beginSession() {
    session = DbUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
}

@Override
public void addUser(String username, String password) {
    User user = new User(username, password);
    beginSession();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    }
}
```

To test the above class,  which is a good method. 
Shall I use mocking to write Junit tests or use an in memory database for testing. 
I don't want to test it with the database that I use for development because the test cases will corrupt it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically in an enterprise you would write two types of test cases. One Unit Test cases where you will use Mockito to stub out object like repository objects etc. The idea is the your functionality is testable even if a db is not available. Another set is integration test cases. This will in fact connect to all the resources etc in the backed to do an end-to-end testing. You can use Maven's surefire plugin to run the test case during run time. A class with name ending in "Test" is considered a Unit Test case and ending in "IT" is an integration test case. Example ("SomeTest", SomeIT). To answer your question you need both Mockito and H2 where H2 being the resource/backend of ur application